# Rails: Prevent id conflict with a method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I am using string as id in routes (e.g. resource/:id ) but id can also be 'new' (a method in my Controller) which rather than showing the resource with id=new, directs to create new resource. How can I restrict users from choosing id=new while creating new resource?

Comment: add a `:before_filter :check_new,  :only => [:new]` & prevent routing to new action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can think of three solutions where you can set string instead of id

**First:** set a combination of the id and the attribute_name, add
in your model

```
def to_param
   return [self.id, self.attr_name].join('-')
end
```

**Second:** prevent the user of adding any action method in your controller (that's safer than restricting only the "new" method, you may add other get methods in the future)

```
validates :attr_name, exclusion: { in: YourController.action_methods.to_a }
```

**Third:**
use [friendly_id](https://github.com/norman/friendly_id) gem

Comment: Thanks a lot! I really appreciate that you gave sample code.

Answer (score 2):

Try to use `exclusion` validation in the model, http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#exclusion

Answer (score 1):

In `config.rb`, change your route to:

```
resources :resources
```

You'll get the routes you need. I have a feeling you'll soon need some of the others that come with it, like `create` and `edit`.

Edit: to make life easier, in your model:

```
def to_param
  return self.my_string_id
end
```

Where `my_string_id` is the string you are using in the URL as the identifier. That will make the URL use that as the :id param instead of the numeric ID.

See: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#resource-routing-the-rails-default